# New sites are created but not showing in My Sites drop down

Tags: wordpress

I've installed the multisite successfully and have everything working as well as I can tell except for the issue at hand. I can create a new site and even access it via the URL but it never shows in the My Sites drop down. I have to go to the Dashboard and click on the Sites icon to view the list. It's also not sending the email when I create the new site.

WordPress 3.5.1 on a localhost running apache

htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /multisite-test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I had the "Options FollowSymlinks" at the top and that didn't seem to help.

As far as I can tell, I'm still able to create and manage sites, the main Dashboard just doesn't appear to be able to show them. I appreciate any help and for my fellow United Statesians, Happy Independence Day!

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if you ever resolved this or not, however since this page was the first to come up with I googled the issue, I figured it could use an answer.

For me, it was human error due to the fact that I was managing so many users. I ended up not assigning them to my overall admin account.

Once you go into the site's users and make sure to add your admin username, the site should show up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never did resolve it but I'm about to start setting it up for my client next week so thanks for your advice. I'll give it a try and let you know how it works!

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Worked like charm.. :)

Comment: Never realised something as simple as this could be the cause of that. Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score 9):

I know this has already been resolved, but I wanted to clarify that for New sites that are created, but that is not showing in the 'My Sites' drop down, these newly created sites need to have the same Super Admin user on every site.

To add the same Super Admin user, click "Sites -> All Sites" on the admin sidebar. Next, click the name of your new site. After your site information shows up, you should see "Info, Users, Themes, Settings." Select Users. You may not see where to add a user, but if you scroll all the way to the bottom you'll see "Add Existing User" and "Add New User." You may not think that your Super Admin is not a user for this new site. You're correct, however the user is a user on the network, so you will "Add Existing User."

You can then Change the role to Administrator if it doesn't automatically pick that up.

Hope this helps some people as this took me some time to find how to fix this issue.

Comment: This is misleading, since you do not need to have the 'same Super Admin'. If you do not add yourself as a member to the given website, you won't see it in your menu. You also need probably correct privileges to enter the administration of that website.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when creating the new site, ensure that you use the Super Admin email.