# Wordpress Portfolio Site - Is there a way to host multiple wordpress templates and link them together?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building my portfolio using wordpress, and I have made several wordpress templates that I want to link to. But I have no idea how I can do that, or if that is even possible.

I was thinking I can:
(A) Somehow use different wordpress templates as the pages of the template used for the portfolio itself.
(B) Host these other templates as totally separate websites and link to them like I would any other website.
(C) Somehow link one template to another.

Which of these choices, if any, is the right choice?

Any suggestions on what I should do at this point to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does this helps: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/

Comment: I think it depends on what you actually mean by “template”. Are you talking in the abstract or specifically a WordPress template? If the latter, the answer is to just create a page for each and select the template. If the former, we’d need to know more, for instance, are you talking about multiple themes? Or is it just that you want a common nav across your templates? If so, most people add a “top top nav” that is shared across all templates and bind that to a menu.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I didn't think about that. I'll elaborate. I made 2 different custom WordPress themes. 1 for practice. Then, I created another theme for my portfolio. Now, I want to find a way to put the original custom theme ONTO this portfolio I made. And I have no idea how to do that, if I can do that. I didn't know if I could host multiple different wordpress sites, each using different custom themes I have made. OR, if there was a way to link 2 different active themes together.

Comment: There’s always WordPress Multisite, which would allow you to have dedicated WordPress sites sharing the same install. That sounds like it might work for you. Big hint for WP MS, however, sites do not “talk” to each other or are even “aware” of each other. A programmer can manually do this, but out of the box, except for the root site, they aren’t aware.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you. I will try that next and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @ChrisHaas OK, so a Multiset DEFINITELY seems like what I was looking for. Now the only problem I have is, I am not able to create any new site. When I try to set up a site, it doesn't get its own dashboard and it doesn't appear in my list of sites. I am able to set a URL and link to it, just like I wanted. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisHaas HA! I figured out what I was looking for. You were totally right. A multisite was exactly what I wanted. And I even found the solution to my new sites not showing up. I just needed to add the correct admin to the user of the new site. I found that answer here: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472866/new-sites-are-created-but-not-showing-in-my-sites-drop-down)